# Does Django+ReactJs refresh just like react by itself?

Tags: reactjs, django

I am currently trying to teach myself django+reactjs. I have been able to get react to load with django run server but it doesn't live update. I can only see updates after I build and re-run django server. Is that how it is suppose to be or am I missing something? Please forgive me I am still very much a noob at programming.

Comment: You might consider this path: `https://medium.com/swlh/django-rest-framework-and-spa-session-authentication-with-docker-and-nginx-aa64871f29cd`.  Only using django to serve the data of your application and using react as a standalone front-end.  I find that a useful pattern.

Comment: react or any other libraries or frameworks builds does not update live since it is a build, the build is done when you are happy with how the website work and won't be changed until you build again.